# How to update PHP in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

I'm new in Linux and have the basic experience with Ubuntu and install LAMP Server. I've successfully installed all using the "apt-get install" method. My problem is I want to update PHP 5.3.2 to PHP 5.3.10. It is possible to do that?  TIA!

Comment: You should ask this on [AskUbuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com), the Stack Exchange site for Ubuntu users.

Comment: since people might land here, he did: http://askubuntu.com/questions/102117/how-to-update-to-php-5-3-10-in-10-04

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any repostory based solution for this as of yet. Instead you could use the packages from this post, to install it in Ubuntu 10.04.
http://thejibe.com/blog/10/5/php-5210-debs-ubuntu-104-lucid

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
>> sudo apt-get update

>> sudo apt-get install php5-cli

>> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: It won't work because the latest version available for this Ubuntu release is not the one which he wants(Its 5.3.2 itself).

Comment: check this link http://thejibe.com/blog/10/5/php-5210-debs-ubuntu-104-lucid